# Special expression concatenation on JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have an expression with value of :

```
${id} (which giving the output "id")
```

And another expression called :

```
${listItem} (which represent an Item object on list)
```

I wanna to concatenate them to be :

```
${listItem.id}
```

Note that i wanna the ${id} value behaves like an attribute inside listItem !

How to do that trick on JSP ?

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using [EL 3.0](https://java.net/projects/el-spec/pages/Operators),
can straight away use `&` operator to combine strings

```
${id} & ${mylist}
```

or using [jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

```
<c:set var="newval" value="${id}${mylist}"/>
<c:out value="$newval" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But still not the answer ! If you read the post again , i wanna to concatenate both of them to be like domain object !

Comment: Check out my update in the `jstl` part and let me if it helps you

Comment: Nope that's not getting the desired result !

Comment: Can you post the expected output ?

Comment: I did some changes for best understanding , check it again !

Comment: Is that `${id}` same for all list items ? or do you iterate it from list  ?

Comment: Yeah it is the same ! because of iteration !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62153/discussion-between-san-krish-and-hatem).